# How can I do to map "timestamp with timezone" to datetime

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, datetime, timezone

I'm using Postgresql and Hibernate and what I want to do is to map "timestamp with timezone" to datetime. I know it's possible but i don't know how.

After looking for some time, I found this question :
[How to map postgresql "timestamp with time zone" in a JPA 2 entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357487/how-to-map-postgresql-timestamp-with-time-zone-in-a-jpa-2-entity)

But unfortunately the answer does not help me.

I tried to annotate the field with this:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
```

But finally, I had problems. So I don't know if I'm on the right way or not.

Can anyone help me please ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution :

I made a class "DateTimeType" that implements the interface "org.hibernate.usertype.UserType" and I annotate my entity field with "org.hibernate.annotations.Type" like this :

```
@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "com.myproject.domain.type.DateTimeType")
private DateTime creationDate;
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using:

```
DateTimeOffset(DateTime, TimeSpan)
```

Initializes a new instance of the DateTimeOffset structure using the specified DateTime value and offset.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the rapidity of your answer ! 
Is it only for C# ? Or is it also available in Java ? I will look at this thank you.